# Passing Parameters to MapReduce Program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to pass some parameters to map program. The values for these parameters need to be fetched from database and these values are dynamic. I know how to pass the parameters using Configuration API. If I write JDBC code to retrieve these values from database in the driver or client and then set the values to configuration API, Then how many times this code will be executed.  The driver code will be distributed and executed on each data node where hadoop framework identifies to run the MR program ?

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes driver code will be executed on each machine.
I suggest to fetch the data outside the map-reduce program and then pass it as a parameter.

Say you have a script to execute then you just fetch the data from database in a variable and then pass that variable to the hadoop job.

I think this will do your work.

Comment: Agree. What about if i have jdbc code in ToolRunner run method. My client or driver can implement Tool Interface and in the ToolRunner run method, i can fetch this data.

Comment: Yes You can also implement a database connection and fetch data in ToolRunner method and then stored it in a variable.

Comment: Driver Code is not executed on multiple times. Per job Driver code executes just once.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you need is big (more than a few kilobytes), Configuration may not be suitable. A better alternative is to use Sqoop to fetch those data from database to your HDFS. Then use hadoop distribute cache so in your map or reduce code, you can just get those data without any parameters passing in.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the values from DB in the driver code. The driver code will execute only once per Job.